# How to downcast Rc<RefCell<dyn io::Write>> into a concrete type?

Tags: rust, dynamic-typing

I want to make a struct which the text output can be either displayed on the console or stored in an internal buffer. If the text is buffered, then I need a method that gives back the text content.

For this aim I use a property named `writer`, which is `dyn std::io::Write` (wrapped into `Rc<RefCell<>>` because it is needed by my real code). Then on struct construction, I create either a `io::stdout()` instance or a `Vec::<u8>::new()` instance for this property.

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::io;

struct A {
    // Rc<RefCell<>> is needed in my real code
    writer: Rc<RefCell<dyn io::Write>>,
}

impl A {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { writer: Rc::new(RefCell::new(io::stdout())) }
    }

    pub fn new_buffered() -> Self {
        Self { writer: Rc::new(RefCell::new(Vec::<u8>::new())) }
    }

    pub fn write(&self, s: &str) {
        let mut writer = self.writer.borrow_mut();
        writeln!(writer, "{}", s).unwrap();
    }

    /// Returns None if the struct is not buffered, otherwise a copy of the buffered output.
    pub fn get_buffer(&self) -> Option<String> {
        match GET_VEC_U8() { // <- Unable to implement this line
            Some(vec_u8)  => {
                Some(String::from_utf8(vec_u8.clone()).unwrap())
            },
            None => None,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A::new();
    a.write("foo");
    println!("Buffer: {:?}", a.get_buffer());

    let b = A::new_buffered();
    b.write("bar");
    println!("Buffer: {:?}", b.get_buffer());
}
```

#### Question

But I can't figure out how to extract the text content (method `get_buffer()`), when the writer is `Vec<u8>`. How can I do it ?

#### My try

I tried to wrap the property into a `Box`:

```
struct A {
    writer: Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn io::Write>>>,
}
```

then use [Box::downcast()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast) on it:

```
impl A {
    pub fn get_buffer(&self) -> Option<String> {
        let writer = self.writer.borrow();
        match (*writer).downcast::<Vec<u8>>() {
            Ok(vec_u8) => Some(String::from_utf8(vec_u8.clone()).unwrap()),
            Err(_) => None,
        }
    }
}
```

but I get this error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `downcast` found for struct `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::io::Write>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:27:25
   |
27 |         match (*writer).downcast::<Vec<u8>>() {
   |                         ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::io::Write>`
```

Comment: The downcast method on a `Box` is only implemented for `Box<dyn Any + 'static>`. You have a `Box<dyn Writer>` here, so you can't downcast. Changing this to something like `Box<dyn Writer + Any + 'static>` won't help, since that's a different type than `Box<dyn Any + 'static>`, so you still won't be able to use the `downcast()` method.

Comment: Your options are either using an enum instead of dynamic dispatch, or implementing a custom trait depending on `Writer` with an additional `get_buffer()` method. This method can easily be implemented for both `Vec<u8>` and `StdOut`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes, I already tried to add `'static`, indeed it still does not work.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thank you, the custom trait solution that you suggested is working as expected

Answer (score 2):

As @SvenMarnach wrote in the comments, writing a custom trait depending on `io::Write` can be a solution

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::io::{self, Stdout};

trait MyWrite: io::Write {
    fn get_buffer(&self) -> Option<String>;
}

impl MyWrite for Stdout {
    fn get_buffer(&self) -> Option<String> {
        None
    }
}

impl MyWrite for Vec<u8> {
    fn get_buffer(&self) -> Option<String> {
        Some(String::from_utf8(self.clone()).unwrap())
    }
}

struct A {
    // Rc<RefCell<>> is needed in my real code
    writer: Rc<RefCell<dyn MyWrite>>,
}

impl A {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { writer: Rc::new(RefCell::new(io::stdout())) }
    }

    pub fn new_buffered() -> Self {
        Self { writer: Rc::new(RefCell::new(Vec::<u8>::new())) }
    }

    pub fn write(&self, s: &str) {
        let mut writer = self.writer.borrow_mut();
        writeln!(writer, "{}", s).unwrap();
    }

    /// Returns None if the struct is not buffered, otherwise a copy of the buffered output.
    pub fn get_buffer(&self) -> Option<String> {
        let writer = self.writer.borrow();
        writer.get_buffer()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A::new();
    a.write("foo");
    println!("Buffer: {:?}", a.get_buffer());

    let b = A::new_buffered();
    b.write("bar");
    println!("Buffer: {:?}", b.get_buffer());
}
```